# best way\practice to use sql in shell scripts

Tags: sql, shell

I want to write shell script that will access database. I have so far I have received following requirements for best practices:

- no sql code in temporary files
- no static sql
- no dynamic sql

I am not sure after above constraints how should I write the scripts. Do you have any best practices that will allow me to write sql statements in shell scripts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: with those 2 last requirements, you can't make sql queries at all... maybe you're being trolled?

Comment: Thanks. I thought that as much. But I am new to writing shell code so I thought there might be some other way I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna write sql statement in your shell script.

On personal experience, you need take care of the following thing (use mysql):

#### attention 1

Do not specify `username` and `passoword` explicitly like `mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD`, write them into file (`~/.my.cnf`) which syntax likes

```
[client]
user=USERNAME
password=PASSWORD
```

then use

```
mysql --defaults-file="~/.my.cnf"
```

#### attention 2

Just extract data you need, knows the differences between `mysql -e` and `mysql -Bse`

#### attention 3

Be care of punctuation `"` and `'`